# Issue in creating REST Service using laravel

Tags: laravel, rest

We are trying to develop an Android app that required a REST API to show data from web server.

We tried to use Laravel resource to create REST service like below:

```
Route::resource('list', 'ListController');


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use mymodel
class ListController extends Controller
{
    public function getShow($id)
    {
        $Jsondata=list($id);
        return $JsonData;
    }

}
```

But it's not working as expected need some token key or some other authentication and authorization need to know how to set.

Comment: You can create an API inside Laravel that your App can hook onto.

Comment: I have same doubt..please help!

Comment: This is very general question. Take a look at laravel's doc and maybe check laracasts.com on how to work with laravel.

Comment: I already visited https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers but did not get proper answer

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport tells you exactly how to do authentication for your api. It uses OAUTH2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
We should utilize the Repository / Gateway design pattern: 

For example, when dealing with the User model, first create a User Repository. The only responsibility of the user repository is to communicate with the database (performing CRUD operations). This User Repository extends a common base repository and implements an interface containing all methods we require:



class EloquentUserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepository
{
    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function all() {
        return $this->user->all();
    }

    public function get($id){}

    public function create(array $data){}

    public function update(array $data){}

    public function delete($id){}

    // Any other methods we need go here (getRecent, deleteWhere, etc) }

Then, create a service provider, which binds your user repository interface to your eloquent user repository. Whenever you require the user repository (by resolving it through the IoC container or injecting the dependency in the constructor), Laravel automatically gives you an instance of the Eloquent user repository you just created. This is so that, if you change ORMs to something other than eloquent, you can simply change this service provider and no other changes to your codebase are required:

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind(
            'lib\Repositories\UserRepository',        // Assuming you used these
            'lib\Repositories\EloquentUserRepository' // namespaces
        );
    }}

Next, create a User Gateway, who's purpose is to talk to any number of repositories and perform any business logic of your application:

use lib\Repositories\UserRepository;

class UserGateway {

    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository) {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

        public function createUser(array $input)
        {
            // perform any sort of validation first
            return $this->userRepository->create($input);
        }}

Finally, create our User web controller. This controller talks to our User Gateway:

class UserController extends BaseController 
{
    public function __construct(UserGatway $userGateway)
    {
        $this->userGateway = $userGateway;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $user = $this->userGateway->createUser(Input::all());

    }}

By structuring the design of your application in this way, you get several benefits: you achieve a very clear separation of concerns, since your application will be adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle (by separating your business logic from your database logic) . This enables you to perform unit and integration testing in a much easier manner, makes your controllers as slim as possible, as well as allowing you to easily swap out Eloquent for any other database if you desire in the future.

For example, if changing from Eloquent to Mongo, the only things you need to change are the service provider binding as well as creating a MongoUserRepository which implements the UserRepository interface. This is because the repository is the only thing talking to your database - it has no knowledge of anything else. Therefore, the new MongoUserRepository might look something like:

class MongoUserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepository
{
    public function __construct(MongoUser $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function all() {
        // Retrieve all users from the mongo db
    }}

And the service provider will now bind the UserRepository interface to the new MongoUserRepository:

 $this->app->bind(
        'lib\Repositories\UserRepository',       
        'lib\Repositories\MongoUserRepository'
);

Throughout all your gateways you have been referencing the UserRepository, so by making this change you're essentially telling Laravel to use the new MongoUserRepository instead of the older Eloquent one. No other changes are required.
```

Answer (score 0):

Number one is that `what is not working?` if you mean that the response is not showing then its because your function actually doesn't even seem to be *going any where*, and number two are you new to Laravel?

Okay if this is what you have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use mymodel;

class ListController extends Controller 
{ 
    public function getShow($id) 
    { 
        $Jsondata=list($id); return $JsonData; 
    }
}
```

Then I can be safe to say a lot of things is wrong.

To my understanding using `Route::resource('list', 'ListController');` in your routes file creates `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` paths, and also expects to see these functions too (I have not proven this to the core though) but thats my understanding.

so you can simply start laravel life by doing having your routes with

```
Route::get('list', 'ListController@show')
```

Then change your `ListController` to something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 

use mymodel;

class ListController extends Controller 
{ 
    public function show($id) 
    { 
        $jsonData= ['my' => 'json data'];
        return $jsonData;
    }
}
```

If this works for you, then cool else so many thing might already be wrong with your setup.

> Note: you might need to take your time to learn to use laravel from the documentation page. If API is your interest then try [DIngo api](https://github.com/dingo/api). Also try to learn to use markup :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Omisakin could you explain how to create the REST service using laravel like authentication and authorization using key

Comment: I can give you an example of 3 places I followed when I was learning too: [Laravel Api with JWT](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-api-using-jwt-authentication-tutorial-from-scratch-exampleexample.html), [TDD with JWT and Dingo](https://dotdev.co/test-driven-api-development-using-laravel-dingo-and-jwt-with-documentation-ae4014260148#.yt0jqtq0b), and [authentication-with-json](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs) Note that they may be for different version of laravel, Don't forget Laracasts & Laravel doc.

Comment: Thanks it will help